# Take over maintenance of packages?

Tags: ros, pocketsphinx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're using 2 packages that have been neglected by the maintainers: ([PocketSphinx](https://github.com/mikeferguson/pocketsphinx) and [rviz_animated_view_controller](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz_animated_view_controller)). Is it going to ruffle any feathers if I fork rosdistro and update the source url and maintainer names? Our main goal here is a Kinetic version.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261097/take-over-maintenance-of-packages?/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2017-05-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Dirk Thomas just started a related Discourse thread: [Releasing repositories form “other” people](https://discourse.ros.org/t/releasing-repositories-form-other-people/1797).

As ROS Answers isn't really suited for discussion, I'd suggest you bring this up there as well.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0